# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable - nginx, minikube, k8s

Tags: kubernetes, devops, minikube, nginx-ingress

Hello I am new to devops
Problem: Unable to access the ticketing.dev from browser (configured using nginx)
I am using nginx and use minikube (running everything locally)

this is my service and deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: arshad/auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

this is my ingress file

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-serv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

this is my

```
NAME             CLASS    HOSTS           ADDRESS         PORTS AGE  
ingress-service  <none>   ticketing.dev   192.168.99.101   80  45m
```

I also added the /etc/hosts ip like ticketing.dev 192.168.99.101 but still I am getting *503 Service Temporarily Unavailable*
Anyone please help.

Answer (score 3):

Hi you have a typo thats why. Your service name is auth-srv when in ingress you are calling service name auth-serv . Change it on ingress to auth-srv instead of  auth-serv .